# Entity Framework Core- The property on entity type is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I was trying to make a composite key in EF core using below line,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PackageMaster>()
  .HasAlternateKey(a => new { a.InstituteId, a.CourseId, a.PackageCode, a.PackageName });
```

where the combination of InstituteId, CourseId, PackageCode, PackageName should be unique. It worked fine but when I am updating a record, say updating packageCode then I am getting below error,

> The property 'PackageCode' on entity type 'PackageMaster' is part of a key and so cannot be modified or marked as modified. To change the principal of an existing entity with an identifying foreign key first delete the dependent and invoke 'SaveChanges' then associate the dependent with the new principal.

I thought that was the problem with the method "HasAlternateKey" so I have updated it to,

```
modelBuilder.Entity<PackageMaster>()
 .HasIndex(a => new { a.InstituteId, a.CourseId, a.PackageCode, a.PackageName })
 .IsUnique();
```

and here is the entity class,

```
[Table(Schema.Institute + "." + nameof(PackageMaster))]
public class PackageMaster
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int PackageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(5)]
    public string PackageCode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string PackageName { get; set; }

    [StringLength(500)]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int InstituteId { get; set; }

    public int CourseId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CourseId")]
    public CourseMaster CourseMaster { get; set; }        

    [Required]
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }

    [StringLength(3)]
    public string CurrencyCode { get; set; }

    public bool GSTIncluded { get; set; }
}
```

but still no luck. Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: can you post entity class, because If you set it's a key and database generated you would get that error.

Comment: @SenadMeškin Posted entity

Comment: @VijayanathViswanathan, After changing to `modelBuilder.Entity<PackageMaster>()
 .HasIndex(a => new { a.InstituteId, a.CourseId, a.PackageCode, a.PackageName })
 .IsUnique();` is still the same error message showing?

Comment: have you find a solution?

Comment: i have same issue and above IsUnique() not working